# How to import xls/xlsx in django models?

Tags: python, django, django-excel

I'm using django-excel to do this function.

This is my view.py

```
def import_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.FILES['file'].save_book_to_database(
               models=['contoh_upload'],
               initializers=[None,0],
               mapdicts=['id','nama','kelas']
             )
            message = "your upload has been uploaded "
            return render(request, 'kastransaksi/transaksi_formupload.html', {'message': message})
        else:
            message = "Failed Upluad data"
            return render(request, 'kastransaksi/transaksi_formupload.html', {'form': form, 'message': message})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'kastransaksi/transaksi_formupload.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my models.py

```
class contoh_upload(models.Model):
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    kelas = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

and this is my template.html

```
<div class="alert-success">{{ message }}</div>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- <input type="file" name="excel_file"> -->
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="input_button" value="UPLOAD" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

but I get this error:

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _legacy_get_response
>     249.             response = self._get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\siswa\transaksi_kas\views.py" in
>   import_data
>     165.                 models=[(contoh_upload, ['nama', 'kelas'], None, 0)],
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_excel__init__.py" in
>   save_book_to_database
>     61.         pe.save_book_as(**params)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\core.py" in save_book_as
>     224.     return sources.save_book(book, **dest_keywords)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources__init__.py" in
>   save_book
>     46.     return _save_any(source, book)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources__init__.py" in
>   _save_any
>     50.     source.write_data(instance)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources\database.py" in
>   write_data
>     248.                 sheet.name_columns_by_row(0)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sheets\sheet.py" in
>   name_columns_by_row
>     140.         self.__column_names = make_names_unique(self.row_at(row_index))
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sheets\matrix.py" in
>   row_at
>     162.             raise IndexError(constants.MESSAGE_INDEX_OUT_OF_RANGE)
>
> Exception Type: IndexError at /transaksi/import_form/ Exception Value:
>   Index out of range

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Comment: `Index out of range`
`C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sheets\matrix.py in row_at, line 162`
`C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\siswa\transaksi_kas\views.py in import_data`
` mapdicts=['nama','kelas'] `

Comment: The error Trace back is a multiple line error message Starting with the word `Traceback` and ending with the actual exception message (what you have posted only).

Comment: Please add it (completely) to the question by editing it.

Comment: i have edited my question @KlausD.

Comment: And it is still incomplete.

Comment: i have completed it @KlausD.

Comment: the example used 'file' but your field has 'excel_file'. Please use request.FILES['**excel_file**'].save_book_to_database(..)